# Nest.js axios HttpModule freezes app initialization

Tags: axios, nestjs

I have a module that goes like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { OtpService } from '@modules/auth/otp/otp.service'
import { OtpResolver } from '@modules/auth/otp/otp.resolver'
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios'

@Module({
  providers: [OtpResolver, OtpService],
  imports: [
    HttpModule.register({
      timeout: 5000,
      baseURL: "some url"
    }),
  ],
})

export class OtpModule {}
```

and then it is imported in app module:

```
import { OtpModule } from '@modules/auth/otp/otp.module'

@Module({
  imports: [
    ....
    OtpModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: GraphqlConnectionService,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AppConfigService],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

everything works if I remove otp module, it also works if HttpModule is not imported there.
I was going by [this](https://ru-nestjs-docs.netlify.app/techniques/http-module) tutorial but id doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to fix this would be very helpful.

UPD: it just freezes on init, here is the output log, all the other modules are initialized correctly and when it comes to otp, it just stops there

```
{"level":"info","message":"TypegooseModule dependencies initialized"}
{"level":"info","message":"TypegooseModule dependencies initialized"}
{"level":"info","message":"TypegooseModule dependencies initialized"}
{"level":"info","message":"TypegooseModule dependencies initialized"}
{"level":"info","message":"GraphQLModule dependencies initialized"}
```

Comment: Any errors? Does the application just hang? No logs? Do you have `logger: false` in your `main.ts`? I'd be very surprised that just importing that module causes a problem

Comment: updated my answer accordingly

Comment: turns out the logger was not logging bootstrap errors, so it was another error, question is closed!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by importing HttpService and HttpModule from @nestjs/axios

replacing

```
import { Injectable, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
```

For this

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
```